# Native javascript bind event switch not working

Tags: javascript

I have this code Visit https://codepen.io/wploey/pen/ZrWNzd
the HTML template must 'is-active' class name on first

How can I re-issue the next is-active to continue binding the click event?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class='is-active'>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){
  // How can I re-issue the next is-active to continue binding the click event ?
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')[0];
  if (current) {
    current.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      current.classList.remove('is-active');
      current.nextElementSibling.classList.add("is-active");
      current = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')[0];
      console.log(current);
    }, false);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I re-issue the next is-active to continue binding the click
>   event?

You need to **bind the event listener** to the other elements as well. (currently, you are binding to only one of them). [Updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQyMMr)

```
(function(){
  // How can I re-issue the next is-active to continue binding the click event ?
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  Array.from( elements ).forEach( s => {
     s.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      bindListener(e);
    }, false);
  });  

  function bindListener( event )
  {
      var current = event.target;
      current.classList.remove('is-active');
      if( current.nextElementSibling ) //will rotate the is-active
      {       
          current.nextElementSibling.classList.add("is-active");
      }
      else
      {
          current.parentNode.children[0].classList.add("is-active");
      }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,  I realized where it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the event listener to the `ul` and then check for the item with the `is-active` class.

```js
(() => {
 const list = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  
  list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   const clickedItem = e.target;
    const isActive = clickedItem.classList.contains('is-active');
    
    if (isActive) {
     clickedItem.classList.remove('is-active');
      
      if (clickedItem.nextElementSibling) {
        clickedItem.nextElementSibling.classList.add('is-active');
      } else {
        // Just setting the first list item as active when the last item is the active one.
        list.firstElementChild.classList.add('is-active');
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.is-active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='is-active'>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

This acts like jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely,  I realized where it was wrong.